# WinForms TreeView Check Events Being Lost

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

When I double-click an unchecked node in a WinForms `TreeView`, it visually goes to checked followed by unchecked.

However only one `AfterCheck` event is fired as detected by the following event handler:

```
private void treeView1_AfterCheck( object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e )
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine( "{0} {1}: {2}", e.Node.Checked, e.Node, e.Action );
}
```

`e.Node.Checked` is `true` even though the visual representation in the GUI is unchecked.

Clicking the checkbox again raises an `AfterCheck` event with `Node.Checked` equal to `false`. The checkbox remains unchecked on the GUI.

Vice-versa for double-clicking a checked node.

I'm compiling for .NET 4.0 with Visual Studio 2010 and running on .NET 4.5.1.

Any way to work around this?

Comment: I added e.Node.Checked to the WriteLine after the others. Edited to be more sane.

Comment: When you double click on check boxes in treeview, not only it makes problem in after check event, also it makes problem in your next mouse down and if you click anywhere else that the treeview itself, your next mouse click will be lost.

I can confirm that the problem doesn't exists in Windows XP, but exists in 7 and 8.1.

Comment: Also mentioned by @HansPassant in an old post : *The Vista version of the native Windows control induced a bug in the TreeView wrapper. It automatically checks an item without generating a notification message that the wrapper can detect to raise the BeforeCheck and AfterCheck event.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you double click on check boxes in treeview, not only it makes problem in after check event, also it makes problem in your next mouse down and if you click anywhere else that the treeview itself, your next mouse click will be lost.

Also mentioned by Hans Passant in an old post : *The Vista version of the native Windows control induced a bug in the TreeView wrapper. It automatically checks an item without generating a notification message that the wrapper can detect to raise the BeforeCheck and AfterCheck event.*

I can confirm that the problem doesn't exists in Windows XP, but exists in 7 and 8.1.

To solve the problem, you can hanlde [`WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-lbuttondblclk?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) message and check if double click is on check box, neglect it:

```
public class ExTreeView : TreeView
{
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK)
        {
            var info = this.HitTest(PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
            if (info.Location == TreeViewHitTestLocations.StateImage)
            {
                m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
                return;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```