# WinForms TreeView checking/unchecking hierarchy

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview, .net-2.0

The following code is intended to recursively check or un-check parent or child nodes as required.

[image]

For instance, at this position, **A**, **G**, **L**, and **T** nodes must be unchecked if we un-check any one of them.

[image]

The problem with the following code is, whenever I double-click any node the algorithm fails to achieve its purpose.

The tree-searching algorithm starts here:

```
    // stack is used to traverse the tree iteratively.
    Stack<TreeNode> stack = new Stack<TreeNode>();
    private void treeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeNode selectedNode = e.Node;
        bool checkedStatus = e.Node.Checked;

        // suppress repeated even firing
        treeView1.AfterCheck -= treeView1_AfterCheck;

        // traverse children
        stack.Push(selectedNode);

        while(stack.Count > 0)
        {
            TreeNode node = stack.Pop();

            node.Checked = checkedStatus;                

            System.Console.Write(node.Text + ", ");

            if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
            {
                ICollection tnc = node.Nodes;

                foreach (TreeNode n in tnc)
                {
                    stack.Push(n);
                }
            }
        }

        //traverse parent
        while(selectedNode.Parent!=null)
        {
            TreeNode node = selectedNode.Parent;

            node.Checked = checkedStatus;

            selectedNode = selectedNode.Parent;
        }

        // "suppress repeated even firing" ends here
        treeView1.AfterCheck += treeView1_AfterCheck;

        string str = string.Empty;
    }
```

**Driver Program**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        #region MyRegion
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TreeNode a = new TreeNode("A");
            TreeNode b = new TreeNode("B");
            TreeNode c = new TreeNode("C");
            TreeNode d = new TreeNode("D");
            TreeNode g = new TreeNode("G");
            TreeNode h = new TreeNode("H");
            TreeNode i = new TreeNode("I");
            TreeNode j = new TreeNode("J");
            TreeNode k = new TreeNode("K");
            TreeNode l = new TreeNode("L");
            TreeNode m = new TreeNode("M");
            TreeNode n = new TreeNode("N");
            TreeNode o = new TreeNode("O");
            TreeNode p = new TreeNode("P");
            TreeNode q = new TreeNode("Q");
            TreeNode r = new TreeNode("R");
            TreeNode s = new TreeNode("S");
            TreeNode t = new TreeNode("T");
            TreeNode u = new TreeNode("U");
            TreeNode v = new TreeNode("V");
            TreeNode w = new TreeNode("W");
            TreeNode x = new TreeNode("X");
            TreeNode y = new TreeNode("Y");
            TreeNode z = new TreeNode("Z");

            k.Nodes.Add(x);
            k.Nodes.Add(y);

            l.Nodes.Add(s);
            l.Nodes.Add(t);
            l.Nodes.Add(u);

            n.Nodes.Add(o);
            n.Nodes.Add(p);
            n.Nodes.Add(q);
            n.Nodes.Add(r);

            g.Nodes.Add(k);
            g.Nodes.Add(l);

            i.Nodes.Add(m);
            i.Nodes.Add(n);


            j.Nodes.Add(b);
            j.Nodes.Add(c);
            j.Nodes.Add(d);

            a.Nodes.Add(g);
            a.Nodes.Add(h);
            a.Nodes.Add(i);
            a.Nodes.Add(j);

            treeView1.Nodes.Add(a);
            treeView1.ExpandAll();

            button1.Enabled = false;
        } 
        #endregion
```

**Expected to happen:**

Take a look at the screenshot of the application. ***A***, ***G***, ***L***, and ***T*** are checked. If I uncheck, say, ***L***,
 - ***T*** should be unchecked as ***T*** is a child of ***L***.
 - ***G*** and ***A*** should be unchecked as they will have no children left.

**What is happening:**

This application code works fine if I single-click any node. If I double-click a node, that node becomes checked/unchecked but the same change is not reflected on the parent and children.

Double-click also freezes the application for a while.

**How can I fix this issue and obtain the expected behavior?**

Comment: If it's about checking/unchecking, it's better to rely on `AfterCheck` event rather than mouse events. Also take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36295017/3110834).

Comment: @yahoo.com: This is the second question I've seen from you today that really does not provide enough details.  Please be very specific describing what you expect to happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: "...whenever I double-click any node, it is considered as a single-click and the algorithm breaks down." - You do not specify what you expect to happen.  Also "the algorithm breaks down" doesn't tell us anything about what *is* happening.

Comment: You disconnect the `AfterCheck` event handler.  So the first click of a double-click turns it off, and the second click of the double-click occurs during the processing of the first click.  The event handler, having been disconnected, is never triggered for the second click.   You might consider using a bool flag instead of disconnecting the handler and adding each "click" to a Stack of click events.

Comment: I didn't checked your algorithm. If you are sure your algorithm is correct, you can stick to your own algorithm after fixing first two problems which I mentioned in the post. Anyway, my code is working as expected.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

These are the main problems to solve here:

- **Prevent `AfterCkeck` event handler from repeating the logic recursively.**

  When you change `Checked` property of a node in `AfterCheck`, it cause another `AfterCheck` event which may lead us to an stack overflow or at least unnecessary after check events or unpredictable result in our algorithm.
- **Fix `DoubleClick` on check-boxes bug in `TreeView`.**

  When you double click on a `CheckBox` in `TreeView`, the `Checked` value of the `Node` will change twice and will be set to original state before double click, but the `AfterCheck` event will raise once.
- **Extension Methods to get Descendants and Ancestors of a Node**

  We need to create methods to get descendants and ancestors of a node. To do so, we will create extension methods for `TreeNode` class.
- **Implement algorithm**

  After fixing above problems, a correct algorithm will result in what we expect by click. Here is the expectation:

  When you check/uncheck a node:

  - All descendants of that node should change to the same check state.
  - All nodes in ancestors, should be checked if there is at least one child in their descendants checked, otherwise, should be unchecked.

After we fixed above problems and creating `Descendants` and `Ancestors` to traverse tree, it's enough for us to handle `AfterCheck` event and have this logic:

```
e.Node.Descendants().ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    x.Checked = e.Node.Checked;
});
e.Node.Ancestors().ToList().ForEach(x =>
{
    x.Checked = x.Descendants().ToList().Any(y => y.Checked);
});
```

**Download**

You can download a working example from the following repository:

- [r-aghaei/TreeViewCheckUnCheckHierarchyExample](https://github.com/r-aghaei/TreeViewCheckUnCheckHierarchyExample)
- [Zip File](https://github.com/r-aghaei/TreeViewCheckUnCheckHierarchyExample/archive/master.zip)

### Detailed Answer

**Prevent `AfterCkeck` event handler from repeating the logic recursively**

In fact we don't stop [`AfterCheck`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.aftercheck?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) event handler from raising `AfterCheck`. Instead, we detect if the `AfterCheck` is raised by user or by our code inside the handler. To do so, we can check `Action` property of the event arg:

> To prevent the event from being raised multiple times, add logic to
>   your event handler that only executes your recursive code if the
>   `Action` property of the `TreeViewEventArgs` is not set to
>   `TreeViewAction.Unknown`.

```
private void exTreeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown)
    {
        // Changing Checked
    }
}
```

**Fix `DoubleClick` on check-boxes bug in `TreeView`**

As also mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36296641/3110834), there is a bug in `TreeView`, when you double click on a `CheckBox` in `TreeView`, the `Checked` value of the `Node` will change twice and will be set to original state before double click, but the `AfterCheck` event will raise once.

To solve the problem, you can handle [`WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-lbuttondblclk?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) message and check if double click is on check box, neglect it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class ExTreeView : TreeView
{
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK)
        {
            var info = this.HitTest(PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
            if (info.Location == TreeViewHitTestLocations.StateImage)
            {
                m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
                return;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
}
```

**Extension Methods to get Descendants and Ancestors of a Node**

To get Descendants and Ancestors of a Node, we need to create a few extension method to use in `AfterCheck` to implement the algorithm:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public static class Extensions
{
    public static List<TreeNode> Descendants(this TreeView tree)
    {
        var nodes = tree.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>();
        return nodes.SelectMany(x => x.Descendants()).Concat(nodes).ToList();
    }
    public static List<TreeNode> Descendants(this TreeNode node)
    {
        var nodes = node.Nodes.Cast<TreeNode>().ToList();
        return nodes.SelectMany(x => Descendants(x)).Concat(nodes).ToList();
    }
    public static List<TreeNode> Ancestors(this TreeNode node)
    {
        return AncestorsInternal(node).ToList();
    }
    private static IEnumerable<TreeNode> AncestorsInternal(TreeNode node)
    {
        while (node.Parent != null)
        {
            node = node.Parent;
            yield return node;
        }
    }
}
```

**Implementing the algorithm**

Using above extension methods, I'll handle `AfterCheck` event, so when you check/uncheck a node:

- All descendants of that node should change to the same check state.
- All nodes in ancestors, should be checked if there is at list one child in their descendants checked, otherwise, should be unchecked.

Here is the implementation:

```
private void exTreeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown)
    {
        e.Node.Descendants().ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            x.Checked = e.Node.Checked;
        });
        e.Node.Ancestors().ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            x.Checked = x.Descendants().ToList().Any(y => y.Checked);
        });
    }
}
```

**Example**

To test the solution, you can fill the `TreeView` with the following data:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    exTreeView1.Nodes.Clear();
    exTreeView1.Nodes.AddRange(new TreeNode[] {
        new TreeNode("1", new TreeNode[] {
                new TreeNode("11", new TreeNode[]{
                    new TreeNode("111"),
                    new TreeNode("112"),
                }),
                new TreeNode("12", new TreeNode[]{
                    new TreeNode("121"),
                    new TreeNode("122"),
                    new TreeNode("123"),
                }),
        }),
        new TreeNode("2", new TreeNode[] {
                new TreeNode("21", new TreeNode[]{
                    new TreeNode("211"),
                    new TreeNode("212"),
                }),
                new TreeNode("22", new TreeNode[]{
                    new TreeNode("221"),
                    new TreeNode("222"),
                    new TreeNode("223"),
                }),
        })
    });
    exTreeView1.ExpandAll();
}
```

---

## .NET 2 Support

Since .NET 2 doesn't have linq extension methods, for those who are interested to have the feature in .NET 2 (including the original poster) here is the code in .NET 2.0:

**ExTreeView**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class ExTreeView : TreeView
{
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK) {
            var info = this.HitTest(PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
            if (info.Location == TreeViewHitTestLocations.StateImage) {
                m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
                return;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    public IEnumerable<TreeNode> Ancestors(TreeNode node)
    {
        while (node.Parent != null) {
            node = node.Parent;
            yield return node;
        }
    }
    public IEnumerable<TreeNode> Descendants(TreeNode node)
    {
        foreach (TreeNode c1 in node.Nodes) {
            yield return c1;
            foreach (TreeNode c2 in Descendants(c1)) {
                yield return c2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**AfterSelect**

```
private void exTreeView1_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown) {
        foreach (TreeNode x in exTreeView1.Descendants(e.Node)) {
            x.Checked = e.Node.Checked;
        }
        foreach (TreeNode x in exTreeView1.Ancestors(e.Node)) {
            bool any = false;
            foreach (TreeNode y in exTreeView1.Descendants(x))
                any = any || y.Checked;
            x.Checked = any;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: You could replace `m.Result = IntPtr.Zero; return;` with `m.Msg = 0x0201;` in your custom treeview. Mapping to two single clicks, instead of swallowing the second click, would provide a more intuitive user experience (as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14758596)).

Comment: @Funk Thanks for the feedback, it makes sense. I'll investigate more and probably will update that piece of code :)

Comment: *Prevent AfterCkeck event handler from repeating the logic recursively*  and *Fix DoubleClick on check-boxes bug in TreeView* are completely  .NET 2.0 Compliant. Also the algorithm is not dependent to .NET version, however the implementations which I shared depends on .NET 3.5. But they are not hard to implement in .NET 2.0

Comment: Added support for .NET 2.0 ;)

Comment: My gosh you saved me probably a whole day's worth of work.  This is a gem.  Thanks!