# Prevent user from altering Check boxes in TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, checkbox, treeview

I have a winforms treeview with nodes added and check state set programmatically based on the database values. I am trying to prevent users from altering the check status and am having trouble. I am not sure what event to fire to keep the check state unaltered.

Below is my code:

```
private void BuildRolesTree(int ParentID, TreeNode pNode, DataSet SourceDS)
    {
        
        DataView dvwData = new DataView(SourceDS.Tables[0]);
        dvwData.RowFilter = "[parent_id] = " + ParentID;
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            BuildReportTreeDelegate d = new BuildReportTreeDelegate(BuildRolesTree);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { ParentID, pNode, SourceDS });
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (DataRowView Row in dvwData)
            {
                TreeNode zNode;

                if (pNode == null)
                    zNode = tv_Permissions.Nodes.Add(Row["node_id"].ToString(), Row["display_access_description"].ToString().Trim());
                else zNode = pNode.Nodes.Add(Row["node_id"].ToString(), Row["display_access_description"].ToString().Trim());

                if (Convert.ToInt32(Row["is_selected"]) == 1)
                    zNode.Checked = true;
                else if (Convert.ToInt32(Row["is_selected"]) == 0)
                    zNode.Checked = false;
                                    


                BuildRolesTree(Convert.ToInt32(Row["node_id"].ToString()), zNode, SourceDS);
            }
        }
    }

    private void PermissionsNode_AfterCheck(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {           
       if(e.Action != TreeViewAction.Unknown)
       {
            if(e.Node.Checked) //leave it checked
               e.Node.Checked = e.Node.Checked????
               //I am looking for something like the below
               //e.Checked.NewValue = e.Checked.CurrentValue;
       }    
     }
```

}
ANy help is appreciated.

Comment: Handle [BeforeCheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.beforecheck?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and set `e.Cancel=true` based on a criteria.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What criteria should I be basing on?

Comment: If you want them always readonly, then no criteria is needed.

Comment: If you post your solution, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle [BeforeCheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.beforecheck?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and set `e.Cancel = true` to prevent changing the check:

```
private void treeView1_BeforeCheck(object sender, TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
}
```

However, there is a [problem in TreeView when double click on CheckBoxes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36296641/3110834) the check events not work as expected. Follow the solution that I've shared in the linked post or use the following `ExTreeView` which has a `CheckBoxEdit` property (similar to `LabelEdit`) which allows you enable or disable checking on CheckBoxes:

```
public class ExTreeView : TreeView
{
    private const int WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203;
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK)
        {
            var info = this.HitTest(PointToClient(Cursor.Position));
            if (info.Location == TreeViewHitTestLocations.StateImage)
            {
                m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
                return;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
    [DefaultValue(true)]
    public bool CheckBoxEdit { get; set; } = true;
    protected override void OnBeforeCheck(TreeViewCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnBeforeCheck(e);
        e.Cancel = !CheckBoxEdit;
    }
}
```